# dynamically extracting data from HTML page

Tags: python, class, html-parser

I'm working on a script to extract some string/data from HTML document (Nagios status page, in this case) using this custom class:

```
## tagLister.py

from sgmllib import SGMLParser
class TAGLister(SGMLParser):

    def reset(self):
        SGMLParser.reset(self)
        self.urls = []

    def start_td(self, attrs):
        CLS = [ v for k, v in attrs if k == 'class' ]
        if CLS:
            self.urls.extend(CLS)
```

Whenever a < td > tag is found, SGMLParser is called by `start_td` and look for the `CLASS` attribute.

```
>>> import urllib, tagLister
>>> usock = urllib.urlopen("http://www.someurl.com/test/test_page.html")
>>> parser = tagLister.TAGLister()
>>> parser.feed(usock.read())  
>>> for url in parser.urls: print url
>>> ...
```

The above lists all the values found in the `<td>` tag for the *CLASS* attributes.
Is there any way to dynamically assign the `td` bit (in `start_td`) and `class` (as the value of `k`), so that using `optparse`, it can be assigned on the fly, like this:

```
tagLister.py -t td -k class
```

rather then coding it statically? I'm intended to [re]use this class for any tag (e.g. `<a>`, `<div>` etc.) and the associated attributes (e.g. `href`, `id` etc.) from the command-line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Constantinius You can't see the question? The line start with `Is there any way.....` is my question, I guess. Or you pointing out that fact that I forgot put a `?` in the end? If you understand what I actually meant, then be my guest to improve the question. Cheers!!

Comment: @Constantinius: The question is how to take values given on the command line and use those in parsing HTML instead of the current static values.

Comment: `SGMLParser` is somewhat ancient technology; is switching to BeautifulSoup or lxml an option? What you are asking is certainly possible, but things are easier with those.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Is BeautifulSoup or lxml part of the Python stranded library? One limitation here: I can only use the things that comes with python up to version 2.7

Comment: @MacUsers: Why the limitations? No, BeautifulSoup and lxml are external libraries.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: This is gonna be the part of our AntHill-Pro (AHP) work-flow, where servers are installed and maintained by a completely separate group and asking for something which is not part of the standard installation will only cause our work to be delayed and eventually will not happen. (Pretty much standard office-story, I guess??) Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: There are great tools to package python code and manage dependencies. See http://guide.python-distribute.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to switch to `lxml.html` and use XPath - and the result of that will already be a list... (and since an XPath expression is just a string - it's easier to formulate than playing around with class inheritance)

```
>>> tag = 'a'
>>> attr = 'href'
>>> xpq = '//{}/@{}'.format(tag, attr)
>>> a = '<a href="test-or-something">hello</a><a>No href here</a><a href="something-else">blah</a>'
>>> import lxml.html
>>> lxml.html.fromstring(a).xpath(xpq)
['test-or-something', 'something-else']
```

**if you have to use stdlib - then you could do something similar with HTMLParser**

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class ListTags(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, tag, attr):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.tag = tag
        self.attr = attr
        self.matches = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
         if tag == self.tag:
            ad = dict(attrs)
            if self.attr in ad:
                self.matches.append(ad[self.attr])

>>> lt = ListTags('a', 'href')
>>> lt.feed(a)
>>> lt.matches
['test-or-something', 'something-else']
```

Comment: Thanks John for showing me another way. Unfortunately I've to stick with the Python stranded library function at the moment. It was useful though. cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers added another option that uses standard library only - not too happy with it though, but proves it works

Comment: Worked just fine; thanks a lot!! Compare to the lxml, it's really messy but that's my only option at the moment, I guess.